# General solution for nonlinear ODE arbitrari systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

I would like to know if there is a way to represent the solution of a nonlinear system of ode in a general way.

For example, in the case of a linear system, the solution $\varphi(t)$ can be represented as a function of the eigenvalues $\lambda_{k}$ ​​and eigenvectors $v_{k}$ for the jacobian matrix in the equilibrium point, i.e,

$$\varphi(t) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}C_{k}e^{\lambda_{k} t}v_{k}$$

where $C_{k}$ are de constants.
I have found very little literature about it; here I mean that we talk about nonlinear systems but I have not found a way to represent the solution.